# what is session.selectOne(String arg0, Objectarg1);?

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

i am new to MyBatis,i am unable to find tutorials to learn,present i am going to start working on MyBatis with Spring,i had used `session.selectOne(String arg0, Object arg1)` but i am not able to understand how it works and what it will do with the second parameter that is Object arg1.

can any one help in this.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `selectOne` and `selectList` is for a *parameter*. It can be a *primitive* if you have very simple needs in your query, say a single integer, or for more complicated queries requiring many values to be interpolated, a *bean class* instance with the values populated as needed (and containing the proper *getters* and *setters*).

In your *mapper file* you then define the type of the parameter via the *parameter* attribute, and can then interpolate either inline or with escaping (the former for things that should never be escaped, such as variable table or column names, and the latter for things which should always be escaped, such as values in a `WHERE` clause).

See the MyBatis doc for more detail:
http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html

**Response to comments from OP:**

`MapBuilder` must be custom code related to `Map` data structures. There's an `ImmutableMap.Builder` as part of *Guava*, but that doesn't seem like what this is. I don't think it's related to *Mybatis* per se.

It looks like that code is just building up a Map object, and then passing it off to the `selectOne` query for use within the query definition in the *mapper* (instead of a custom *bean* class).

What's the definition on *LoginMapper.getUserByUsername* in your mapper? In that definition, the contents of the map object are likely being interpolated into the query so dynamic values can be included.

Comment: 'Map<String, Object> map = new MapBuilder().addData("username", loginEntity.getUserName()).getMapObject();
LoginEntity dbLoginEntity = session.selectOne("LoginMapper.getUserByUsername",map);'

Comment: what does that mean,,,? how mapper used there as second argument in session.SelectOne("",map);can u please elaborate a little more!

Comment: That looks like perhaps old Mybatis code. `MapBuilder` doesn't appear at all in the code for Mybatis-3 (https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/search?q=MapBuilder). What version are you trying to use?

Comment: i am using MyBatis 3.2.7

Comment: I still do not see any indication of that class in 3.x. I see a `MapperBuilderAssistant` class in the code. http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html defines how to utilizes *Mapper*s in Mybatis-3.

Comment: ok the approach might be old.but i would like to know what it will do with that map object?

Comment: Edited answer w/ add'l info.